# Why the String returned by String.toLowerCase() is not interned?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I was asked to predict the output of this code :

```
String party1 = "party";
String party2= "PARTY".toLowerCase();
if(party1==party2){
   System.out.println("EQUAL");
}else{
   System.out.println("NOT EQUAL");
}
```

I thought the result of `toLowerCase()` would be interned automatically and hence the same reference to `party1` would be returned, but I was wrong since the code ouptuts **"NOT EQUAL"**.
Does `toLowerCase()` (`toUpperCase()` as well) return a new `String` ?

**Edit** : I am not using == to compare Strings, I just want to know about the behaviour of toLowerCase() method

Comment: Why did you expect it to not return a new string?

Comment: Never, ever rely on `==` for string comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: "I thought the result of toLowerCase() would be interned automatically" — What made you think that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use equals() for that end, my question was about the specific implementation of toLowerCase()

Comment: "I thought the result of toLowerCase() would be interned automatically" did you mean that you thought an instance of the string would be returned from the string pool if one exists? If so, no: there is no (public) mechanism to query whether a string exists in the string pool, other than by calling `intern()` and seeing if the same string comes back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the result of any String operation were internalised, the pool would be growing extremely and unnecessarily rapidly. Any intermediate action on a Spring would result in a new element in the pool. It would be beneficial for a VERY small number of cases within a VERY specific domain. Therefore, it's not the default policy and that's why `intern()` exists.

```
String party1 = "party";
String party2 = "PARTY".toLowerCase().intern();
System.out.println(party1 == party2 ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL");
```

There is nothing special about `toLowerCase()`: any `String` method would return a new `String` since `String`s are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is in `String.toLowerCase()` method itself.. as you can check by your self `toLowerCase()` method returns a new lowercase string (a new String object) and `==` checks for the object reference and returns true if they are same which are different in your case.. that's why its returning false.. hope you get it.

```
public String toLowerCase(Locale locale) {
    if (locale == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    ........

    ............

    return new String(result, 0, len + resultOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable.Generally whenever we try to modify a string a new string literal is created in the Constant literal pool and a new reference to it is returned.Although "party" and "PARTY".toLowerCase() have same values i.e. party but in constant pool they refer to two different literals and have two different references. By using `==` operator you are comparing references and not the values.Since they have different references it prints `NOT Equal`.Try  using `party1.equals(party2)` and it will print `EQUAL` as it compares content and not reference.

[image: Constant literal pool and its references]

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge on any operations on string it will duplicate the string so never use '==' instead use  .equals()

```
String party1 = "party";
        String party2= "PARTY".toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(party1);
        System.out.println(party2);
        if(party1.equals(party2)){
           System.out.println("EQUAL");
        }else{
           System.out.println("NOT EQUAL");
        }
```

This gave the result equal